# EXCEL 2010: Using `MID` formula with incremental values in final num_chars

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Program:** EXCEL 2010
**Experience:**  Average

**Question**
How do I get my num_chars value to be an increasing value?
In the example below my `MID` are 6 & 5 respectively, however the digits they represent will increase over time (they are generated on an order basis).

I have some with as little as 5 & 4, and envisage that they will increase to 7 & 6 over time.  Let me show you:

**Productnameorderdetails(Product ID: ####  Order ID: ####)**
  *Productnameorderdetails* are not set digits, they have variable lengths, however the layout of the information (as above) is always the same.

```
Example 1, num_char = 5, this will be 4 (earlier orders) and 6 in the future.  
=MID(A2,SEARCH("Product ID:",A2,1)+11,5)    
(A2)= Productnameorderdetails(Product ID: ####  Order ID: ######)
```

Extracting the middle Product ID #### in my case: 1234
I could increase the value to 6, however the final string `Order ID etc` will then be included in my number.

```
Example 2, num_char = 6, this will be 5 (earlier orders) and 7 in the future.  
=MID(A1,SEARCH("Order ID:",A1,1)+10,6)  
(A1)= Productnameorderdetails(Product ID: ####  Order ID: ######)
```

Extracting the final ###### eg: 123456
I could increase the value to 7, however the final `)` will then be included in my number.

I've had a look and it seems that this would be a great example to use the `LEN` formula with, however I don't know how to implement it & what I have tried keeps breaking.

The goal is that I need to extract the ProdID & OrderID in to their own columns, without any () or spaces then autofill to the bottom of the page and have it update automatically, there are too many rows, I don't want to have to manually scroll through checking for shorter/longer number values.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for Product ID:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1;FIND(":";A1)+1;FIND("Order";A1)-FIND(":";A1)-1))
```

And this to Order ID:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("Order";A1)-8))
```

Depending on your Regional Settings you may need to replace ";" by ","

You're right did not notice the ")".... use this instead:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1;FIND("Order";A1)+9;LEN(A1)-FIND("Order";A1)-9))
```

Comment: Thank you, the ProdID works, it returns the correct value, however the Order ID is still returning the final `)` I have altered the -8, to a -9 & a -7 however it still returns the `)`

Comment: Sweet, that one you submitted still wasn't right, but I fiddled and instead of -9, I had it as -10 and it works.  What would be the reason?  `=TRIM(MID(C86,FIND("Order ",C86)+9,LEN(C86)-FIND("Order ",C86)-10))`

Comment: I think that's because you have a space between last digit and ")", can you show me the exact, complete, string?

Comment: Thank you :)  I've accepted the answer.  Using the same information above, how would I extract just the far left of the "(Product", so that only the Productnameorderdetails will resolve?

Comment: N/M  found it, sorry :)  Thank you for all of your help! :)